# django 2.0 path aren't added

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

i use path instead of url in django 2.0
but there is a problem

Following is my code

```
oauth2_endpoint_views = ([
path('authorize/', oauth2_views.AuthorizationView.as_view(), name='authorize'),
path('token/', oauth2_views.TokenView.as_view(), name='token'),
path('revoke-token/', oauth2_views.RevokeTokenView.as_view, name='revoke-token'),
], 'oauth2')

    if settings.DEBUG:
oauth2_endpoint_views += ([
        path('application/', oauth2_views.ApplicationList.as_view(), name='list'),
        path('application/register', oauth2_views.ApplicationRegistration.as_view(), name='register'),
        path('application/<int:pk>/', oauth2_views.ApplicationDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
        path('application/<int:pk>/delete/', oauth2_views.ApplicationDetail.as_view(), name='delete'),
        path('application/<int:pk>/update/', oauth2_views.ApplicationUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
        path('authorized-tokens/', oauth2_views.AuthorizedTokensListView.as_view(), name='authorized-token-list'),
        path('authorized-tokens/<int:pk>/delete/', oauth2_views.AuthorizedTokenDeleteView.as_view(), name='authorized-token-delete'),
    ], 'oauth2')
```

I added path, but i can't found path **application, application/register ...**

how can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
path('application/register',oauth2_views.ApplicationRegistration.as_view(), name='register'),
```

with

```
path('application/register/', oauth2_views.ApplicationRegistration.as_view(), name='register'),
```

Comment: Following is error message :
Using the URLconf defined in onappscan.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
core/
api/
o/ authorize/ [name='authorize']
o/ token/ [name='token']
o/ revoke-token/ [name='revoke-token']
admin/
api-auth/
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, o/application/, didn't match any of these.
I can't find url in settings.DEBUG